Sign of the first eigenfunction of the Laplacian
I am trying to prove that the first eigenfunction of the Laplacian operator in an open domain $\Omega$ does not change sign and that the first eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ is simple (with Dirichlet-boundary conditions $u|_{\partial\Omega}=0$).
I have prooved that $\lambda_1$ is simple if and only if the first eigenfunction $u$ does not change sing (by the usual technique of considering $u^+$ and $u^-$).
I am struggling to prove either property by itself alone, and the references I have found for this are quite vague and have not helped me. I think that the proof may need to use the fact that the first eigenfunction is the first minimizer of the Rayleigh quotient:
$\lambda_1=\frac{\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2}{\int_\Omega u^2}$
but I haven't been able to use it.
I would appreciate any help regarding this question. Thanks in advance for your help!

This is a well-known result in quantum mechanics relating the number of nodes to the energy eigenstate (arranging the eigenvalues from least to greatest). Your situation specifically describes the infinite potential well in higher dimensions. There is a proof under very general considerations linked in this answer.

Have a look in Evans' PDE textbook, Chapter 6. There is a very nice concrete proof of this.

Look at proposition 2.4 on page 369 of "Partial Differential Equations I" by M. Taylor. The proof is the same as in Evans book.
